# Can Netlogo be used to simulate complex agents?

Tags: netlogo

I am new to Netlogo and I would like to create an extension of the ant colony optimization algorithm by "complexifying" the ants. This means the agents (the ants) are not point-like or particle-like, but have to take into account various factors in their  environment before acting a certain way. I would like to be able to create ants with sub-modules, where each sub-module can interact with other sub-modules as well as with a part of the environment. Is this possible in Netlogo? Any resources on this would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is exactly what NetLogo is for.

In NetLogo terminology, your ants would be turtles. Turtles have attributes (what I think you mean by submodules) such as speed, carrying capacity etc. They interact with each other and the environment (patches in NetLogo), so can pick up food, take it home, decide whether to fight or run away or whatever. If you can describe the factors that determine the behaviour, then you can program that behaviour.

NetLogo has a brief but useful tutorial at its main site, an extensive library of models built in, and links to resources.